# POSTing a nested object - returning the nested object inside the parent

Tags: rest

Suppose that we have a Post resource (this is just a dummy example):

*GET /api/posts/1*

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "header": null,
  "content": null
}
```

And now we'd like to create a Header inside the Post#1.

*POST /api/posts/1/header*

```
{
  "color": "blue",
  "title": "Some title"
}
```

**Now, is it okay for the POST request above to return the following response?**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "header": {
    "id": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "title": "Some title"
  },
  "content": null
}
```

So, basically, a Header was created inside the Post and returned as part of the Post.

Also, if we need to GET the header for Post#1:

*GET api/posts/1/header*

```
 {
   "id": 1,
   "color": "blue",
   "title": "Some title"
}
```

So here only the Header is returned.

**Edit:** Formatted JSON following @Mike Slinn response.

Answer (score 0):

Nested JSON objects are not a problem.

The problems with the JSON that you show are:

- Single quotes are used instead of double quotes. Perhaps you are writing in Python and serializing a dict into JSON? If so, no problem. Otherwise, you need to replace the single quotes with double quotes.
- Similarly, the keys need to be double-quoted.

```json
 {
   "id": 1,
   "color": "blue",
   "title": "Some title"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Please don't pay attention to the JSON. I am just interested in the question (marked in bold) --> Now, is it okay for the POST request above to return the following response?

Comment: I answered "yes"